# Does jFreeChart work/comple in Android 2.x

Tags: java, android, jfreechart

Does jFreeChart compile and run in Android 2.2 or above?   I tried to run it and received missing swing class errors.  There does not seem to be any definitive answer on the web.   The answer to this question is either 1) Yes,  I use it all the time, here are the steps or 2) No,  It doesn't work because **_**.

I just want to put this issue to rest and get a definitive answer.  So please don't suggest other chart packages.

Thanks

Fish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JFreeChart **will not compile/run** in Android as is because it relies on swing packages.  Swing components are not used by Android, and not included in Android's version of Java.

Answer (score 6):

I see another port of JFreeChart for Android:

http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/

It looks good. You can see its screenshots here:

http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a port of JFreeCharts to Android. I don't know how complete it is. You can give it a try:

http://code.google.com/p/droidcharts/