# how to use FFT to filter a 50Hz noise from a data array?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have a data array from an ECG like this one

http://joachim.behar.perso.neuf.fr/Joachim/ECG_tuto_1/ECG_filters_basics/ecg_sample.txt

and I need to filter a 50Hz noise out of it, using an algorithm like that

http://joachim.behar.perso.neuf.fr/Joachim/ECG_tuto_1/ECG_filters_basics/notch_filter.m

and the result should be like that ( red - filtered, blue - unfiltered ) seen in [Figure 2](http://joachim.behar.perso.neuf.fr/Joachim/ECG_tuto_1.php):

[image]

What would be the best way of doing it in Java/android? Would this library help https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms ?

Thanks! )

Comment: I'm not an expert in Android. 
Is there any problem doing FFT->filtering 50hz out->FFT^-1?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11539455

Comment: multiplication in the frequency domain is convolution in the time domain. Convolution might be faster than FFT.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad knowledge of the subject, but that's FFT and what's Convolution and how can one use it? )

Comment: I found an FFT library here https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms , what do you think, would it fit?

Comment: @RogerTravis Did you succeed in finding a solution for your question?

Answer (score 2):

In the article [*ECG elementary filtering*](http://joachim.behar.perso.neuf.fr/Joachim/ECG_tuto_1.php), a *notch filter* is applied in the (mis-numbered) section on *Removing power line noise*; the result is displayed in [Figure 2](http://joachim.behar.perso.neuf.fr/Joachim/ECG_tuto_1.php). This Java [`ImageJ`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imagej/info) [plugin](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-16.html#toc-Section-16), [`Notch_Filters`](http://svg.dmi.unict.it/iplab/imagej/Plugins/Image%20Restoration/Notch_Filters/Notch_Filters.java), "implements the most common Notch filters in the frequency domain." While the example is not directly portable to android, it might allow you to select a particular implementation to re-implement.

Note that the article expands on the limitations of the approach.

Addendum: The notch filter relies on an FFT, so you'll need both.

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks. Just how would it be getter to implement that notch filter into a common android activity? :)

Comment: I'm not sure. What activity? EKG? Telephony? What noise?

Comment: a simple android activity, that has an array from this file http://joachim.behar.perso.neuf.fr/Joachim/ECG_tuto_1/ECG_filters_basics/ecg_sample.txt and needs to filter off the 50hz noise.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about an android UI. I'd definitely prototype on the desktop; [tag:jfreechart] is my [favorite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513), and android [ports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4788576/230513) are available.